# Rotating sprite from angle a to angle b in libGdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a little problem with a simple path following AI.
If i use `setRotation()` the sprite has a sudden rotation but I need to rotate it in a gradual and natural way.

I have very low knowledge of trigonometry so i ask here.

```
public class AISprite extends Sprite {
    private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
    private float speed = 100; 
    private Array<Vector2> path; // it contains viewpoints
    private int waypoint = 0;  // index of actual waypoint

    public AISprite(Sprite sprite, Array<Vector2> path){
        super(sprite);
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        super.draw(spriteBatch);
    }

    public void update(float delta){
        float angle = (float) Math.atan2(path.get(waypoint).y - getY(),    path.get(waypoint).x - getX());
        velocity.set((float) Math.cos(angle) * speed,(float) Math.sin(angle)*speed);
        rotation(angle);


        // if the last waypoint is reached, start again
        if(isWaypointReached()){
        if(waypoint + 1 >= path.size)
            waypoint = 0;
        else
            waypoint++;

        }


}

private void rotazione(float angle){
    setRotation(angle*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees); 
}

private boolean isWaypointReached() {
    return Math.abs(path.get(waypoint).x - getX()) <= speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() 
            &&
            Math.abs(path.get(waypoint).y - getY()) <= speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}

public Array<Vector2> getPath(){
    return path;
}
public int getWaypoint(){
    return waypoint;
}
```

Comment: if your getting sudden rotation then you need to probably slowly update the amount you are rotating by on each update until you reach the new direction. If you want to make it even more natural you could add in some acceleration and deceleration.

Comment: Create a member variable `float mCurrentAngle;` and a constant `static final float MAX_RADIANS_PER_SECOND = MathUtils.PI2;//(example)`. Then where you're calcuating the angle, use that as a target angle, so `mCurrentAngle = (Math.abs(mCurrentAngle-angle)< MAX_RADIANS_PER_SECOND*deltaTime? angle : (mCurrentAngle>angle ? mCurrentAngle-MAX_RADIANS_PER_SECOND*deltaTime : mCurrentAngle+MAX_RADIANS_PER_SECOND*deltaTime );` `setRotation(mCurrentAngle*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);`

Comment: If you want the motion to look smoother, look up tweening (UniversalTweenEngine) and/or smoothstep.

Comment: The above is simplified. You'll need to expand on this math to determine which direction you want to rotate (whichever direction is the shortest distance around).